# Gson json to object with custom FieldNamingPolicy

Tags: android, json, xml, gson

In an android project, i created classes extracted from a xsd files that look something like this

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LoginUserResponse1Document", propOrder = {
    "lgnUsrRspn"
})
public class LoginUserResponse1Document {

    @XmlElement(name = "LgnUsrRspn", required = true)
    protected LoginUserResponseV01 lgnUsrRspn;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lgnUsrRspn property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LoginUserResponseV01 }
     *     
     */
    public LoginUserResponseV01 getLgnUsrRspn() {
        return lgnUsrRspn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lgnUsrRspn property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LoginUserResponseV01 }
     *     
     */
    public void setLgnUsrRspn(LoginUserResponseV01 value) {
        this.lgnUsrRspn = value;
    }
}
```

The api im working with uses the names that appear in `@XmlElement(name = "LgnUsrRspn", required = true)` for example in one of the requests i get a response in json that looks like this:

```
{
  "LgnUsrRspn": {
    "Hdr": {
      "XchgId": "7403AC2E976D46968F6B4839E2FCB7A6",
      "DtTm": "2017-04-05T09:20:47.593+0000",
      "NxtFlow": "LOG"
    },
    "LgnUsr": {
      "Rslt": {
        "RsltStts": "DECL",
        "RsltRsn": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have this class to handle the json conversion

```java
public class JsonBuilder {

    private JsonBuilder(){
    }

    public static String toJson(Object pojo){
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        return gson.toJson(pojo);
    }

    public static Object fromJson(String json, Class type){
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
}
```

My question is if there is a way i can create a custom FieldNamingPolicy to use with GsonBuilder, or a way i can use the name that i have in `@XmlElement(name = "LgnUsrRspn", required = true)`

Comment: why can't you just annotate your fields with another annotation like `@SerializedName("LgnUsrRspn")` for GSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setFieldNamingStrategy()` that allows you to pass your own `FieldNamingStrategy` implementation.

For example,

```java
public class XsdAnnotation implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field field) {
        XmlElement fieldNamingPolicy = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
        return fieldNamingPolicy.name();
    }
}
```

But i would recommend to use it with `@SerializedName`.

Comment: @Ric Did you check my answer?

Comment: yes, sorry, i was out for lunch  thanks for the help